# Using Protostuff on Android causes RuntimeException because of missing sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory

Tags: java, android, protostuff

I'm trying to use [Protostuff](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff) version 1.7.2 in Android to serialize and deserialize some user-defined classes. I'm generating the Protostuff's schema's during runtime with the `RuntimeSchema.getSchema()` method. However, I'm running into a RuntimeException when I call this method.

I've pinned down the issue to `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory` not existing in Android. Protostuff tries to load this class [here](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff/blob/master/protostuff-runtime/src/main/java/io/protostuff/runtime/RuntimeEnv.java#L169), but appearently can't do so on Android, causing the return value [here](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff/blob/master/protostuff-runtime/src/main/java/io/protostuff/runtime/RuntimeEnv.java#L328) to be `null`, which triggers the RuntimeException. I tried to run the same code (see below) on Ubuntu/Windows, there my code runs fine because the installed Java runtime includes `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory`.

```
final DefaultIdStrategy STRATEGY = new DefaultIdStrategy(IdStrategy.DEFAULT_FLAGS
                | IdStrategy.ALLOW_NULL_ARRAY_ELEMENT
                | IdStrategy.MORPH_COLLECTION_INTERFACES
                | IdStrategy.MORPH_MAP_INTERFACES
                | IdStrategy.MORPH_NON_FINAL_POJOS);
schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(clazz, STRATEGY);
```

I tried to use [protostuff-runtime-md](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff/tree/master/protostuff-runtime-md), which should work on Android, but no luck.

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work on Android?